# If i increase 'num.replica.fetchers', would it increase my overall throughput?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm creating a topic with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and produce with acks of "all" and trying to run some tests to see performance.

After reading some articles on kafka performance, I observed that setting replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and produce with acks of "all" would reduce the throughput compared to acks 1. Now I'm trying to understand if i increase the  'num.replica.fetchers', would it help to increase the throughput?

Answer (score 1):

`num.replica.fetchers` is a cluster-wide configuration setting that controls how many fetcher threads are in a broker.

These threads are responsible for replicating messages from a source broker (that is, where partition leader resides).

Increasing this value results in higher I/O parallelism and fetcher throughput. Of course, there is a trade-off: brokers use more CPU and network.

default value 1

The following are some good articles on Kafka Performance.

https://www.slideshare.net/JiangjieQin/producer-performance-tuning-for-apache-kafka-63147600

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/processing-trillions-of-events-per-day-with-apache-kafka-on-azure/

https://medium.com/@rinu.gour123/kafka-performance-tuning-ways-for-kafka-optimization-fdee5b19505b

Comment: Thanks @Rohit for sharing the links, I would go through them.

Comment: hope, it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, increasing the number of fetchers COULD help increase the throughput since *consumers only ever read fully acknowledged messages*. But there seems to be an optimal number of fetchers to be determined which could depend on your specific scenario & other settings. Check this out (section 4): https://www.instaclustr.com/the-power-of-kafka-partitions-how-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-kafka-cluster/